# Is the fingerprint logon for Windows Hello reader specific?

Tags: fingerprint, biometrics, windows-hello

I cannot login to windows using a fingerprint reader different from the one I setup my fingerprint on. Is the fingerprint captured on one reader not compatible with another? I have one reader that needs the finger to be slide across and another that reads on touch.

Can I not log in because they are of different type or are fingerprints captured by different vendor readers incompatible? ([MS Support](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hello/is-windows-hello-fingerprint-hardware-vendor/3c22aa4f-ae2b-4e66-a654-f73bb0d881af?messageId=f2a6f5e2-57f6-4596-aee1-67b87f6289a8))

Slide: https://amzn.to/2PIVxAU

Touch: https://amzn.to/2MxxyGN

[image: Compare Fingerprint readers]

Comment: Yes, they're not compatible. The imaging process is different and often result in different images. On top of that the storage "format" is managed by the different drivers in different ways.

Comment: I assume you have confirmed that both devices, actually support Windows 10 Hello, one of those devices the support seems questionable at best.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia - Where is that documented.  Everything I know about `Windows 10 Hello` is that it standardized biometrics through a standard interface, now if it comes down to the scanner's are a different quality that might make sense.  However, I would expect the format and imaging process to be identical, between the two `Windows 10 Hello` compatiable devices

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, different quality, different resolutions, etc. result in different images. An image scanned by one might not match the now scanned image from a different device. I use Windows once in a blue moon so I wasn't aware of such standardization. In Linux it's often the case that old stored fingerprints scanned by one aren't matched when using a different reader.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia - If we were talking about Windows 7, where you must use a third-party application, in order to use biometrics to logged into your user I would agree with your assessment.  I don't necessarily disagree with it though, I was just wondering, where it was documented that different devices wouldn't be compatible with one another.

Comment: @Ramhound You're probably right about Windows 10 and I have zero experience with biometrics in that version.

Comment: @Ramhound - yes both manufacturers claim to support Windows Hello and they actually work. I tried https://github.com/djbozkosz/Windows-Biometric-Framework-FingerPrint-Example and am able to capture png images from the sliding sensor, but the touch sensor crashed the app. But that might just be a deficient app.